# Error while making GitHub Actions CI build to fail when vulnerable nuget package is found in dotnet projects

Tags: .net, grep, nuget, github-actions

I'm checking on ways to make GitHub Actions CI build to fail when a vulnerable nuget package is found in the projects within solution. Here is the [repo](https://github.com/ILoveDotNet/ilovedotnet).

Initially, I had the following simple command in the [`deployment.yml`](https://github.com/ILoveDotNet/ilovedotnet/blob/main/.github/workflows/deployment.yml#L50):

```yaml
# Check Vulnerable Nuget Packages
- name: Checking Vulnerable Nuget Packages
  run: dotnet list package --vulnerable --include-transitive
```

But this doesn't make the build to fail. So after some googling I found that it is possible to make the build fail when vulnerable packages are found as per the following [article](https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/check-if-your-dotnet-app-dependencies-has-a-security-vulnerability-on-you-cicd-pipelines/). So I modified the above yml as follows:

```yaml
# Check Vulnerable Nuget Packages
- name: Checking Vulnerable Nuget Packages
  run: |
    dotnet list package --vulnerable --include-transitive 2>&1 | tee build.log
    echo "Analyze dotnet vulnerable nuget package command log output..."
    grep -q -i "critical\|high\|moderate\|low" build.log; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "Security Vulnerabilities found in Nuget Packages on the log output" && exit 1
```

And here are the logs for the above command:

```
Run dotnet list package --vulnerable --include-transitive 2>&1 | tee build.log
  dotnet list package --vulnerable --include-transitive 2>&1 | tee build.log
  echo "Analyze dotnet vulnerable nuget package command log output..."
  grep -q -i "critical\|high\|moderate\|low" build.log; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "Security Vulnerabilities found in Nuget Packages on the log output" && exit 1
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    DOTNET_ROOT: /usr/share/dotnet

The following sources were used:
   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

The given project `Web` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `BaseComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `BlazorDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `SharedModels` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `OOPSDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `UITests` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `DependencyInjectionDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `SharedComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `LINQDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `DesignPatternDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `ReportDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `HTTPClientDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `MiddlewareDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `PythonDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `SOLIDDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `TDDDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `WebAPIDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `CommonComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
Analyze dotnet vulnerable nuget package command log output...
Security Vulnerabilities found in Nuget Packages on the log output
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The above logs say there are no vulnerable packages in any of the project, but the build still failed. So I decided to print the contents of the `build.log` to see what's wrong in it. And here is the updated command:

```yaml
- name: Checking Vulnerable Nuget Packages
  run: |
    dotnet list package --vulnerable --include-transitive 2>&1 | tee build.log
    echo "printing build.log..."
    cat build.log
    echo "Analyze dotnet vulnerable nuget package command log output..."
    grep -q -i "critical\|high\|moderate\|low" build.log; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "Security Vulnerabilities found in Nuget Packages on the log output" && exit 1
```

and here is the output of the above command:

```
Run dotnet list package --vulnerable --include-transitive 2>&1 | tee build.log
  dotnet list package --vulnerable --include-transitive 2>&1 | tee build.log
  echo "printing build.log..."
  cat build.log
  echo "Analyze dotnet vulnerable nuget package command log output..."
  grep -q -i "critical\|high\|moderate\|low" build.log; [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "Security Vulnerabilities found in Nuget Packages on the log output" && exit 1
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    DOTNET_ROOT: /usr/share/dotnet

The following sources were used:
   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

The given project `Web` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `BaseComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `BlazorDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `SharedModels` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `OOPSDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `UITests` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `DependencyInjectionDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `SharedComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `LINQDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `DesignPatternDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `ReportDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `HTTPClientDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `MiddlewareDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `PythonDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `SOLIDDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `TDDDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `WebAPIDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `CommonComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
printing build.log...

The following sources were used:
   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

The given project `Web` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `BaseComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `BlazorDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `SharedModels` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `OOPSDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `UITests` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `DependencyInjectionDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `SharedComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `LINQDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `DesignPatternDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `ReportDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `HTTPClientDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `MiddlewareDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `PythonDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `SOLIDDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `TDDDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `WebAPIDemoComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
The given project `CommonComponents` has no vulnerable packages given the current sources.
Analyze dotnet vulnerable nuget package command log output...
Security Vulnerabilities found in Nuget Packages on the log output
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Still the build fails. Please can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Anything wrong with the `grep` command?

**Update 1:**

The answer accepted works fine in case when vulnerability is present but fails when no vulnerability is present. And thats because of the change in json structure. I have requested for update in answer.

Here is the `No Vulnerabilties Found` case json result.

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "parameters": "--vulnerable --include-transitive",
  "sources": [
    "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"
  ],
  "projects": [
    {
      "path": "/home/runner/work/ilovedotnet/ilovedotnet/Web/Web.csproj"
    },
    {
      "path": "/home/runner/work/ilovedotnet/ilovedotnet/BaseComponents/BaseComponents.csproj"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the `Vulnerabilities Found` case json result

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "parameters": "--vulnerable --include-transitive",
  "sources": [
    "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"
  ],
  "projects": [
    {
      "path": "/home/runner/work/NugetVulnerabilityCheck/NugetVulnerabilityCheck/NugetVulnerabilityCheck/NugetVulnerabilityCheck.csproj",
      "frameworks": [
        {
          "framework": "net6.0",
          "topLevelPackages": [
            {
              "id": "System.Net.Http",
              "requestedVersion": "4.3.3",
              "resolvedVersion": "4.3.3",
              "vulnerabilities": [
                {
                  "severity": "High",
                  "advisoryurl": "https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7jgj-8wvc-jh57"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the new sample [repo](https://github.com/fingers10/NugetVulnerabilityCheck) used to evaluate the answers.

Comment: Try: `if grep -q -i "critical\|high\|moderate\|low" build.log; then echo "Vulnerabilities found" && exit 1; else echo "No vulnerabilities found"; fi`

Comment: still it fails saying "Vulnerabilities found". Here is the CI run output - https://github.com/ILoveDotNet/ilovedotnet/actions/runs/8035873657/job/21948940132

Comment: That solution with `grep` in itself is not robust. You should something like JSON and use that for decision making. See its spec [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-Machine-readable-output-for-dotnet-list-package#-dotnet-list-package---vulnerable---format-json). Currently, it's failing because `low` is part of the word `fol*low*ing` which is being checked. Apart from that, some module's name may also include the terms being checked in `grep`. Using JSON will make it more robust and such cases won't break your workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with `grep` command i.e.:

```bash
grep -q -i "critical\|high\|moderate\|low" build.log
```

scans the complete `build.log` including:

```
The following sources were used:
   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

and, here it matches the word "low" with "fol**low**ing" and that's why it's failing.

You may tweak the regex to handle that; but in future, the component name or the log message itself may contain the strings being checked by the `grep` regex resulting in failure.

A more robust solution would be to use the JSON format.

Starting .NET SDK 7.0.200, `dotnet list package` subcommand offers a `--format` flag that may be used to generate JSON output:

- [Spec](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-Machine-readable-output-for-dotnet-list-package#-dotnet-list-package---vulnerable---format-json)
- [`dotnet list package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package) command

The JSON key `severity` can be checked with the [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) command to identify the vulnerabilities.

Here's an example (https://jqplay.org/s/Ym9kqW4LbCe):

```bash
dotnet list package --vulnerable --include-transitive --format=json > list.json
if jq -cre '.projects | .. | .severity? // empty' list.json; then
  echo 'Vulnerabilities found! Exiting...'
  jq . list.json
  exit 1
else
  echo 'No vulnerabilities found!'
fi
```

It:

- dumps the JSON output to `list.json` file
- recursively checks for `severity` key under `projects`
- returns zero if there are any `severity` KV pairs

  - in case of success, it dumps the complete JSON on the console
  - you may run the same command again to print the console output if JSON is not suitable to show on the console
- returns non-zero exit code if there are no severity keys

---

You can adjust this solution to fail your workflow for some specific severity level e.g. "**Critical**" by updating `jq` filter i.e. `select(test("Critical"))`:

```bash
dotnet list package --vulnerable --include-transitive --format=json > list.json
if jq -cre '.projects | .. | .severity? // empty | select(test("Critical"))' list.json; then
  echo 'Vulnerabilities found! Exiting...'
  jq . list.json
  exit 1
else
  echo 'No vulnerabilities found!'
fi
```

You can further expand this solution according to your complete use case as you deem fit e.g. you might want to add validation checks for the intermediate nodes, etc.

Comment: I just completed the same but in complicated way. Your answer looks simple and clean. Can you add another section to your answer showcasing the logic to make build fail only for `Critical` severity value?. This will make the answer more complete and gives options for readers to choose from. I tried changing to `.projects | .. | select(.severity == "Critical")` but this doesn't work... Your magic touch and expertise can help.

Comment: @fingers10: Answer updated for the specific severity level. Please check the last section.

Comment: The command fails when there is no vulnerabilities..The json structure when there is no vulnerability doesn't have project node.. I think your solution should check for existense of `projects` node and then `frameworks` aray and then `topLevelPackages`  array or `transitivePackages` array and compare the severity value.. I tried removing the project node in the above jqplay link that you have shared and it breaks. I have updated the question with json on no vulnerability cases.

Comment: @fingers10: Yes, it should fail when there's no vulnerabilities (or no vulnerabilities of the specified severity level in case of the last update). The JSON has the `projects` node present even when there's no vulnerabilities. Here's the JSON for your project: https://jqplay.org/s/Ne_XrJbmF4T.

Comment: I have added a test project with vulnerable package to validate the answer. Here is the run link - https://github.com/fingers10/NugetVulnerabilityCheck/actions/runs/8036448922/job/21950156328 . And the checks is not capturing the vulnerable package with your solution. Please check the yml file and logs. I'm also checking

Comment: @fingers10: That's working fine. Please recheck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256975/discussion-between-fingers10-and-azeem).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the .NET 8 SDK and Visual Studio/MSBuild 17.8, NuGet can now "audit" packages on restore: https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/concepts/auditing-packages

It was also announced in the .NET 8 release notes, and NuGet's 6.8 release notes and blog posts.

Even if your projects are still targeting .NET 6 or .NET 7, you can still use the .NET 8 SDK (build tools) to target the older target frameworks, so you don't need to limit yourself to the older .NET SDKs that don't support this feature.

NuGet Audit is enabled by default, but currently only checks direct package references. Additionally, it currently requires nuget.org to be a package source (technically any package source that provides the vulnerabilities database will enable the feature, but I'm only aware of nuget.org as this time), but I'm currently working on a feature to enable it even for solutions that don't use nuget.org as a package source. However, I believe the same is effectively true for `dotnet list package --vulnerable`, which I'll probably also need to change once `auditSources` is implemented.

If you want NuGet Audit to check transitive packages as well, either add `<NuGetAuditMode>all</NugetAuditMode>` to all your projects, perhaps by putting it an Directory.Build.props file. Alternatively, you can test it with `dotnet restore -p:NuGetAuditMode=all`.

If you want restore to fail when a vulnerability is detected, you can use `<WarningsAsErrors>$(WarningsAsErrors);NU1901;NU1902;NU1903;NU1904</WarningsAsErrors>`, or the various other ways you can get MSBuild to treat warnings as errors.

Keep an eye out on the NuGet Audit docs for upcoming features.

Comment: I came across auditing packages before posting the question here. But looks like this support is only with Visual Studio. I was looking for a solution which is IDE independent. Hence didn't follow this.

Comment: no, it's built into restore, so it works anywhere that restore works, including `dotnet restore`.  I'm honestly baffled how you'd come to the conclusion that it's VS only. Everywhere it's document it says it's available from the .NET 8.0.100 SDK.